# How can one eliminate/minimize water wave reflections in a ripple tank?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, reflection, boundary-conditions, home-experiment

Is there any way to prevent or minimize reflections of water waves in something like a ripple tank? I'm thinking maybe something analogous to acoustic sound panels (I believe they use foam properties to absorb sound) could be helpful. Or alternatively, maybe something analogous to shock absorbers would be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You can buy a sponge-like substance called *open cell foam* or *fully reticulated foam* which looks like a block of sponge but has a very large cellular structure in which all the cells are interconnected ("reticulated") with open passages. This stuff is used to fill the fuel tanks of race cars to prevent the fuel from flowing freely out of the tank should it get ruptured in an accident.

It is available in a variety of pore sizes, from a fraction of a millimeter to several millimeters, and comes in sheets and blocks. You can line the walls of the ripple tank around the water line with the coarsest available foam sheet and it will damp out surface waves of wavelength ~several centimeters. Add thickness until you obtain the right amount of damping.

If you can't find any of this you can instead try the coarsest available grade of *stainless steel wool* which is like ordinary steel wool but is noncorrosive.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will definitely try your suggestion when I have the time.